# In RStudio -How do I import a csv dataset with no columns specified?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, data-import

I'm working with a medical device called a visual fields perimeter that outputs a semicolon delimited list but does not specify columns in the csv and I'd like to specify how many items constitutes a complete record so it can be made into a table. I'm working in RStudio to do statistical analysis on the data.

Example where each four values follow the following template [x-value, y-value, seen(yes/no), color(red/blue)]

```
1;2;yes;blue;3;4;no;red;4;7;yes;blue;5;4;yes;red
```

so here there are 4 complete records but no way this is indicated.

In reality my template has 13 variables but this is a simplified example.

thanks so much for any guidance

Comment: *"outputs a semicolon delimited list but does not specify columns in the csv"* I'm confused about the file format. First off, a CSV file is *always* comma-delimited (the "C" in CSV stands for "comma"); since you state that entries are separated by semi-colons this is not a CSV file. Secondly, do you mean to say that in your file rows are not separated by line breaks? Is that the challenge here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting the question to mean: "How do I import (into R) semicolon-delimited data with no line breaks when the number of columns is known?"

You can do this with `read.delim()` by specifying `header=FALSE` and indicating the number of columns with the length of the `col.names` argument.

```
input_text <- "1;2;yes;blue;3;4;no;red;4;7;yes;blue;5;4;yes;red"
read.delim(text=input_text, sep=";", col.names=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), header=F)

#   a b   c    d
# 1 1 2 yes blue
# 2 3 4  no  red
# 3 4 7 yes blue
# 4 5 4 yes  red
```

Comment: Or `read.table`, since `read.delim` calls `read.table(..., header=TRUE)` while `read.table` is `header=FALSE` by default. - so `read.table(text=txt, col.names=c("a","b","c","d"), sep=";")`